# document.getElementsByName() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript. I have a web form and I want to get some fields from the form. When the user completes the input the variable `a` is undefined, does it mean the value of input didn't save in `a`.

```
    function validateForm() {
        var a = document.getElementsByName("Firstname").value;
            if (a == null || a == "") {
                alert  ("please fill firstname box");
                return false;
             }
        else {
                $('.box2').hide();
                $('#education').fadeIn();
                $('#edu-step').addClass('active');
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of the HTML form that goes with this? `getElementsByName` may not be the method for your form.

Comment: Undefined means that it is undefined.

Comment: <form class="form" id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="personal-info">
       <div class="col-6">
<input type="text" id="FirstName" name="Firstname" placeholder="نام" lang="fa-IR" runat="server" required="required" />
        </div></div></form>

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByName("Firstname")` will return a list of elements, so `document.getElementsByName("Firstname").value` will be undefined, use

```js
function validateForm() {
    var a = document.getElementsByName("Firstname")[0].value;
    alert(a);
    if (a == null || a == "") {
        alert  ("please fill firstname box");
        return false;
    }

    else {
        $('.box2').hide();
        $('#education').fadeIn();
        $('#edu-step').addClass('active');
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    }
}
```

```html
 <form class="form" id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="title H3" id="head-text">
            پرسشنامه استخدام
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 purchase_steps">
            <a class="steps active" id="person-step">
                <div class="circle-step" id="step1"></div>
                <div class="line-step"></div>
                <label for="textstep" class="text-step">مشخصات فردی</label>
            </a>
            <a class="steps" id="edu-step">
                <div class="circle-step" id="step2"></div>
                <div class="line-step"></div>
                <label for="textstep" class="text-step">سوابق تحصیلی و آموزشی </label>

            </a>
            <a class="steps" id="work-step">
                <div class="circle-step" id="step3"></div>
                <div class="line-step"></div>
                <label for="textstep" class="text-step">سوابق کاری</label>


            </a>
            <a class="steps" id="other-step">
                <div class="circle-step" id="step4"></div>
                <div class="line-step"></div>
                <label for="textstep" class="text-step">اطلاعات تکمیلی</label>

            </a>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="div1">

        <div class="step1">

            <div class="box2" id="personal-info">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="step1 col-12">
                        <div class="title H4">
                            مشخصات فردی<hr />
                        </div>
                        <div class="personal-info">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <label for="FirstName" id="Label2" text="Label" runat="server">نام</label>
                                <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="Firstname" placeholder="نام" lang="fa-IR" runat="server" required="required" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <label for="Lname">نام خانوادگی</label>
                                <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder=" نام خانوادگی" lang="fa-IR" runat="server" required="required" />
                            </div>
                     
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button type="button" class="nextStep" onclick="validateForm()">مرحله بعد</button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
       
    </div>

    <div id="div3">
      

    </div>
    <div id="div4">
        
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: many thanks for your kind attention, but when i use suggestion code in debugger i have error"Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: can you show your html code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b412p4h7/

Comment: it seems to be working, check the snippet above

Comment: what you changed in my code??, it doesn't work for me in local project :(

Comment: also in jsfiddle that send for you it is not working.